# Node removal and event handlers

Tags: html, dom, events, handlers

Just interesting...
What happens to node's event handlers when I remove it completely from the DOM tree? That means, if I create a node with the same id as removed node later, will it have the same event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no event handlers on the new node, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try It using the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console. Just removing a node and then recreating It with the same ID would answer your question.